# How can I make a Grails domain class show the name field?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I am using a class to populate a list and but the drop-down list on my view shows the fully qualified name of the class only:

```
com.pomodoro.Product : 2
com.test.Product : 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the bottom of your class:

```
String toString() { return name }
```

You need to override the `toString()` class method